How to disable indentation guides in Visual Studio Code?
I am having an issue with Visual Studio Code where indentation guides are appearing, cutting the code intentionally. They connect opening and closing blocks in files like HTML. I've tried disabling this feature by adjusting the settings in Visual Studio Code, but so far, I haven't been able to resolve it.
I've attached an image showing the issue for better visualization.

Can anyone help me disable these indentation guides? What setting or adjustment should I make?
I tried disabling the Indentation Guides, but it didn't work.

Guides: Indentation
Search your settings for "guide". Uncheck the box "Editor > Guides: Indentation".
See screenshot below:

Sticky scroll
The sticky scroll feature shows what you see at the top of your screenshot.
To disable that one, search your settings for "sticky scroll enable". Uncheck the "Editor > Sticky Scroll: Enable" checkbox.
See screenshot below:


in settings.json:

Open Settings (JSON) by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + P (Mac), then search for Preferences: Open Settings (JSON).

Add this line: "editor.renderIndentGuides": false



I don't really understand why this answer was marked as helpful. This setting has not existed since September 2021 (version 1.61). Or am I mistaken?

Actually the setting does still work (and still exists) but its a good point that the newer settings should be favored over the deprecated ones. @Kashif I would recommend you improve this answer by using the new settings.

The editor.stickyScroll.enabled setting introduced in February 2024 (version 1.87) should be set to false.
If you want to disable the same behavior on tree views, there is a separate setting available since January 2024 (version 1.86), where you need to set workbench.tree.enableStickyScroll to false.

User and Workspace Settings - VSCode Docs
How to open Visual Studio Code's settings.json file - StackOverflow answer
Sticky Scroll - VSCode Docs
VSCode 1.86 line of code started following me in split at top of screen as I scroll. Why? - StackOverflow answer: It's not an answer aimed at turning it off, but it might be useful regarding the topic.

Note: Based on the title is completely different from the content of the question. Although you mentioned that this didn't work, I would clarify that the editor.guides.indentation setting, or "Indentation Guides", controls the vertical guide lines, not the sticky header. However, if you really want to disable it, set it to false.

Indent guides - VSCode Docs
Default indent line guide in Visual Studio Code? - StackOverflow answer

